# Image Segmentation applications

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I wanna experiment k-means clustering method on different kind of images, so I am trying to find different kind of images used in image segmentation such as MRI images.I want to gather some more categories.
Any suggestion would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: You need MRI images for segmentation, or other images? for other categories, you can find here- http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/

Answer (score 1):

I would search for "segmentation benchmark dataset" or so. One of the first results seems to be useful for your task:

https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/segbench/BSDS300/html/dataset/images.html

Comment: This dataset has a more recent version here, https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/resources.html, in case that is useful.